# How to get the address of certain place by using Google APIs

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

This is my first individual project in android. It is a place locator kind of application. I need to search specific places (for e.g the clothing shops) in the certain radius (like 5 km ) of the current location. I am in the initial stage and not getting any idea about the database.

Is it possible to find the specific places without my own data or do I need to create a database or xml which will contain the list of addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

To get an long and lat from an address you can read on this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Hey ysrb ..thanks for your quick reply..I found that i need to use the Google Places API..i will try to implement..Thanks once again..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Geocoder` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html